# How to use two same taxonomy in same post differently?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I am using a taxonomy named "season" for two times under CPT post_cpt.
I am showing one 'season' taxonomy as drop-down using metabox, and another in traditional way.
Now the problem is when I am saving one season taxonomy terms then other season taxonomy is saving automatically.
If I select 2016-17 season terms using metabox then traditional one is automatically saving as 2016-17.
But I don't want to save these two in this way.
If I select 2016-17 using metabox and 2016-18 using traditional one then it will save them differently.
 Please see the image.
[image]

Comment: It's the same piece of data, just like the post title, even if you expose 100 title fields, only one will be saved.

Comment: No Alternative way?

Comment: You need to change the meta_box to pull the taxonomy term list, but store as a custom field.  That's the only solution.  I know ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) does this out of the box for taxonomies with the ability to NOT save term to post.